# how to pass get this for the collection from the fetch:success event?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

Is there a way how to refer to owner-collection from the success-event.
example, i am using `this` where i want to refer to the collection:

```
var col = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: MobileService,
url: 'file.json',

initialize: function(){
    this.fetch({
        success: function(){
            this.trigger('fetched'); 
        },
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch):

> **fetch** `collection.fetch([options])`
>
> [...] The **options** hash takes `success` and `error` callbacks which will both be passed `(collection, response, options)` as arguments.

So you can use:

```
this.fetch({
    success: function(collection) {
        collection.trigger('fetched');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's always:

```
initialize: function(){
    var self = this;
    self.fetch({
        success: function(){
            self.trigger('fetched'); 
        },
```

Comment: damn, so easy. it's time to rest i guess... but doesn't work by some reason.

Comment: my bad. works well... though this is not an optimal solution. thanks anyway!